# How to get the Filtered value of Ag-Grid as string

Tags: ag-grid, pdfmake

[image]

I have the above column api data, from which I want to get the applied filtered value as string, using the **agGridColumnApi?.api?.filterManager?.allFilters** but getting undefined as result.

I have the above column api data, from which I want to get the applied filtered value as string, using the **agGridColumnApi?.api?.filterManager?.allFilters** but getting undefined as result.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use the `getFilterModel` to get all the filters from aggrid, docs for [`filter api here`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-api/)

```
// Gets filter model via the grid API
const model = api.getFilterModel(); 

// Sets the filter model via the grid API
api.setFilterModel(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

api.filterManager.advancedFilterService.appliedExpression
Worked for me.